# Zapier to Monday.com, is there a way to retrieve or save the numerical monday pulse ID to reference later?

Tags: zapier, monday.com

So I have an asknicely.com board that we get customer survey responses from.
I have a Monday.com board where I track these responses and our follow ups for management.

I am using a zapier zap, that filters the responses, that works.  BUT it currently puts all the data I want into a new pulse in the first column only.  Someone has to move it all manually into each column (me) after it arrives.

I am trying to develop a new zap that creates the pulse then puts the data into the correct columns. I have a zapier structure like this.

1. When this happens …  New Response in AskNicely
2. Do this …  New Pulse on a Board in monday.com
3. Do this …  Update column B in Monday.com
4. Do this …  Update column C in Monday.com
5. ... etc.

My issue is that in order to update a now existing pulse (3 onwards) I have to populate `Pulse Id1 2 3` field which accepts only a number.

Here are my questions;

- Can I get Zapier to "catch" the pulse ID upon creation so I can save and reference it later?
- Or can I retrieve the numerical pulse ID by searching with the text field I first created the pulse with? `pulses.getID().contains(someaskicelyTextField);`
- Or lastly, is there a better approach to this than the one Im using?

I have a java background and its frustrating using these visual widgets instead of working in the actual code to do the above.   I am new to both products so if this has been asked before I apologize.

[image: You can see 'id:' field and at end of url in data test (this looks like json)]

[image: this shows the 'pulse Id 1 2 3' field]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

spencemw, you can get the pulseID when you configure the zap.
On the 'Update column value' step, on the item ID, reference the parameter from the previous step.
(Make sure to click the 'show all options')

Comment: Roy, thanks for pointing this out to me.  I will edit my post to include the screen shots.

Answer (score 0):

@Roy Nevo answered.  Here are the screen shots for finding the data I was looking for.

[image: How to find where the data is hiding]

[image: find the actual data]